# Pause the playing video when switch to another div

Tags: asp.net, video

I have 2 div's, one div has swf object & other has tabular data. Both are on same page. I would like to toggle them, if video display table div is hide, and if table then video div will hide.

This is working fine, but when toggle to table div video get started from start. I want to pause the existing video.

So please let me know how can I pause it without restart it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding the div with CSS (display:none;) the SWF file will start rendering as if you are opening the page for the first time or reloading it. First try to use (visibility:hidden;) but you will have to set the position to absolute because this way will preserve div's space on the page.

If this didn't help there is a bridge between javascript in the page and SWF files where you can ask for where the video is playing now before you hide the div, store this on the page, then when you restore the div you can tell SWF to seek to the stored time.

check this as a sample for javascript/AS3 interactions:
http://circlecube.com/2010/12/actionscript-as3-javascript-call-flash-to-and-from-javascript/

Comment: we are creating swf using Adobe Captivate and I think there are no way to add Action script.